# How do you get the Barricade Blaster-Achievement?

Tags: 4-elements

I've gotten all the achievements of the game, except this one. It says 'Clear 20 stone slabs using long chains', and I'm pretty sure I've cleared as much by now.

Do I have to clear them with ONE chain? Or in one level?
I figured it couldn't be that difficult as some 43% of all players on Steam have this achievement, but somehow it won't work for me.

Any ideas on what I am missing, or how I can complete the achievement?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it now, but in case anyone else ever wonders how to get this:

Seems like you need to blast all the rocks in one level. Personally, I got it on Level 27 now, which has quite a few rocks towards the end.